# Maximum size on the bounding box with ST_MakeEnvelope and && and geography column in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, intersection, extents, geography-data-type

I've done quite a few google searches, but haven't managed to find anything that has helped me directly. I've got a few features in a PostGIS table with a geography column. The features are focused around (latitude, longitude) 0, 100 and 1, 101 (those are literally the points for any POINTS or LINESTRINGS in that column).

I'm making a query like this:

```
SELECT GUID, ATTRS, ST_AsGML(GEOG), ACTIVE, CREATED, FTIME 
FROM FEATURES 
WHERE GEOG && ST_MakeEnvelope(99, -3, 103, 3, 4326) 
 AND ACTIVE = TRUE ORDER BY CREATED DESC LIMIT 100
```

And it returns all the data

If I change the query to be much larger, then nothing comes back:

```
SELECT GUID, ATTRS, ST_AsGML(GEOG), ACTIVE, CREATED, FTIME 
FROM FEATURES 
WHERE GEOG && ST_MakeEnvelope(-75, -80, 110, 3, 4326) 
  AND ACTIVE = TRUE ORDER BY CREATED DESC LIMIT 100
```

So is there a limit I'm hitting somewhere here I don't know about it?

If I change the query to this:

```
SELECT GUID, ATTRS, ST_AsGML(GEOG), ACTIVE, CREATED, FTIME 
FROM FEATURES 
WHERE GEOG && ST_MakeEnvelope(-70, -80, 109, 3, 4326) 
  AND ACTIVE = TRUE ORDER BY CREATED DESC LIMIT 100
```

I still get all my data back!

**EDIT**

Added the ST_AsEWKT(GEOG) as requested:

```
select ST_AsEWKT(GEOG) from features;
             st_asewkt             
-----------------------------------
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;LINESTRING(100 0,101 1)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;LINESTRING(100 0,101 1)
 SRID=4326;LINESTRING(100 0,101 1)
 SRID=4326;LINESTRING(100 0,101 1)
 SRID=4326;LINESTRING(100 0,101 1)
 SRID=4326;LINESTRING(100 0,101 1)
 SRID=4326;LINESTRING(100 0,101 1)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
 SRID=4326;POINT(100 0)
```

Comment: Can you show the ST_AsEWKT(GEOG) for a couple of points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Envelopes and the geography type are almost always a bad mixture, since they are not comparable (i.e., [Cartesian vs spherical](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html)). Your results are probably expected if you see them on a round globe.

[With the smaller envelope, I see Sumatra](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=3%B0S+99%B0E-3%B0N+99%B0E-3%B0N+103%B0E-3%B0S+103%B0E-3%B0S+99%B0E&MS=wls&DU=mi):
[image]

But, [with the larger envelope, it goes through the South Pacific](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=80%B0S+75%B0W-3%B0N+75%B0W-3%B0N+110%B0E-80%B0S+110%B0E-80%B0S+75%B0W&MS=wls&DU=mi):
[image]

---

If you need to select features within a box-shaped envelope, cast it to `geometry`, e.g.:

```
SELECT guid, attrs, ST_AsGML(geog), active, created, ftime
FROM features
WHERE geog::geometry && ST_MakeEnvelope(-75, -80, 110, 3, 4326) AND active
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Do this if your map is flat, an you expect envelopes to behave in Cartesian space.