# PostGIS ST_MakeEnvelope size direction change on geography

Tags: postgis, boundaries

This doesn't really effect me but I was just wondering if you find this a little bit strange or not. I think this issue is probably cause of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78816/maximum-size-on-the-bounding-box-with-st-makeenvelope-and-and-geography-colum) also but I think the accepted answer does not apply to my question.

I am using [ST_MakeEnvelope](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html) and it tax `xmin`,`ymin`,`xmax`,`ymax` values as arguments.

I realized that for example, if longitude distance is over 180 degrees, it seems to wrap around other way around (That is what I think is happening, I may be wrong?).

I thought it would always go from `xmin` to `xmax`. As in `xmin=-81` to `xmax=100` should go in direction `-81,-80,-79...0,1...100` , yet it seems to make a boundary box going other way `-81,-82,-83...(+/–)180,179...100`

Am I imagining things and is this suppose to work like this? Any reason why this way is better than always assuming we should travel from `xmin` to `xmin+` direction?

```
SELECT tbl1.column1, tbl2.column1, tbl1.column2 && tbl2.column2 AS overlaps FROM 
( VALUES
(1, 'POINT(0 0)'::geography), 
(2, 'POINT(-85 0)'::geography) ) AS tbl1,
( VALUES
(3, ST_MakeEnvelope(-80, -10, 100, 20, 4326)::geography), 
(4, ST_MakeEnvelope(-81, -10, 100, 20, 4326)::geography)) AS tbl2;
```

Results in:

```
 column1 | column1 | overlaps 
---------+---------+----------
       1 |       3 | t
       1 |       4 | f
       2 |       3 | f
       2 |       4 | t
```

Comment: related: [In PostGIS a polygon bigger than half the world is treated as it's opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737506/in-postgis-a-polygon-bigger-than-half-the-world-is-treated-as-its-opposite)

Comment: Antipodal distances are usually either an error or wrapped the great circle direction.

Comment: @JGH yes, I think that issue you linked seems to share the same background.

@Vince The question is why function has `xmin`,`xmax` arguments yet it is designed to chose smallest area and if this is desired behavior or a bug, and if it is desired why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the geography advanced FAQ http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#idm1391 what you experience is intentional

> What is the longest arc you can process?
>
> We use great circle arcs as the "interpolation line" between two
>   points. That means any two points are actually joined up two ways,
>   depending on which direction you travel along the great circle. All
>   our code assumes that the points are joined by the *shorter* of the
>   two paths along the great circle. As a consequence, shapes that have
>   arcs of more than 180 degrees will not be correctly modelled.

Comment: This is a nice answer. I think somebody should tell postgis people to put information about maximum possible ranges on their documentation.

Comment: Great. Now I know why my map works weird. But is there a simple fix for that?